Text Frame Defauls
In one particular file I am using and  editing in inDesign, when I open a new text box it is using a particular character style which I don't want.
How can I stop text boxes opening with a character style I have created?
I want it to open with the default of (none) in character style?
I think I may have set something to make this happen but not sure how to get it back to normal. Any ideas?

Deselect everything.
Click [None] in the Character style panel.
That will stop new text frames from having the character style applied to them.

If a Character (or Paragraph) style is highlighted in the panels before you draw a text frame, that highlighted style is applied to the frame.
